# Subset Extraction from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

I imported a `Dataframe` using `pandas` then wrote some code (as below) to create an additional column. I need to extract a subset of the newly added column and then create an if statement that will allow me to look at the last 2 values of the integers and apply the following logic:

- If the integer ends in 9 perform a +2 addition (for example: 9+2=11)
- For anything else perform a +1 addition (for example 4+1=5)

This is the code I've written so far to create the additional column:

```
max_items['ind_short'] = ((max_items['Item'] % 1000).astype(int))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: provide sample data with expected outcome

Comment: What format is your data?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by `last number within the column` you mean the units value of an integer, you can use the modulo operator `%`. Then use `numpy.where` to perform your mapping:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [6357, 1325, 549, 12312, 19]})

df['B'] = np.where(df['A'] % 10 == 9, 2, 1)

print(df)

       A  B
0   6357  1
1   1325  1
2    549  2
3  12312  1
4     19  2
```